# Redirect main domain to alias domain & change address bar to alias url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, dns, cpanel, alias

I've tried tons of solution that I've found but it's still not working.

I've registered 2 domains in godaddy.

1 - mydomain.com -has the main wordpress site
2 - mydomain.org

I created mydomain.org as the alias domain through mydomain.com's cpanel.

What I want is when we access to mydomain.com, it has the content of mydomain.com but the url on the address bar changes to mydomain.org.

I tried to use redirects tool in cpanel from .com to .org & this gives me error redirection.

I achieved this result by changing the site url in the wordpress to mydomain.org.

But,

both domain have https, when I entered .org, this error came out "your connection is not secure".

I used this in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I'm not sure if all of these are the right approach, from setting up the alias domain as url & forcing the https for the wordpress site

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,P]
```

But this has "some" limitations - you will have to enable mod_proxy and mod_rewrite on your server, if I pressume you are using Apache server.